# CSS Render problems?

Tags: html, css, border

I am currently trying to add some Design to an selfprogrammed board. Somehow I am experiencing odd buggs with the CSS rendering:

[image]

Every Row of that board is a .BoardRow Class to be formated in CSS. So, I am using:

```
.BoardRow td {
    border: 2px dotted #4E6011;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 33%, #EFEFEF 90%); /* Chrome, Safari */
}
```

this to add some nice looking borders around each row. Somehow always the top row is failing to work as intended. When zooming in with CTRL + Mouse in Google Chrome the top border always changes as shown in the picture. What can i do about this?

EDIT: Here is the full generated HTML Code:

```
<div id="Top">
  <div id="Navi"> <a class="Link" href="index.php?s=home">Startseite</a> <a class="Link" href="index.php?s=physicians">Ärzteliste</a> <a class="Link" href="index.php?s=pmr">Polymyalgia Rheumatica</a> <a class="Link" href="index.php?s=logout">Abmelden</a> <a class="Link" href="index.php?s=course">Krankheitsverlauf</a> <a class="Link" href="index.php?s=board">Forum</a> </div>
</div>
<div id="Main">
  <table id="Board">
    Seite (1 von 1)
    <tr>
      <td class="BoardHeadline">Thema</td>
      <td class="BoardHeadline">Beiträge</td>
      <td class="BoardHeadline">Angesehen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="BoardRow">
      <td class="BoardName"><a href="index.php?s=board&threadid=3">asdfasdfas</a> von (Unbekannter Benutzer)<br />
        geschrieben am 25:03:2013 um 15:43 </td>
      <td class="BoardCounter">3</td>
      <td class="BoardCounter">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="BoardRow">
      <td class="BoardName"><a href="index.php?s=board&threadid=5">Titelasdgkljahskjdghkjasg</a> von (Unbekannter Benutzer)<br />
        geschrieben am 25:03:2013 um 16:14 </td>
      <td class="BoardCounter">1</td>
      <td class="BoardCounter">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="BoardRow">
      <td class="BoardName"><a href="index.php?s=board&threadid=6">asdjglkajsljkdg</a> von (Unbekannter Benutzer)<br />
        geschrieben heute um 12:58 </td>
      <td class="BoardCounter">3</td>
      <td class="BoardCounter">12</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <a href="index.php?s=board&action=newthread&where=2">Neues Thema eröffnen</a> </div>
<div id="UserPanel"> <a href="index.php?s=profile">Benutzerprofil</a> </div>
```

and here is the CSS:

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/252C5rTn)

Please note that i am not an HTML or CSS expert. ;)

I am using Google Chrome 19 (old portable version on my usb stick) but this is also occuring on the local installed IE 8.

Comment: Please post your *full* CSS and HTML structure. Also, try putting together a jsFiddle. There's not enough information there to answer your question.

Comment: If it's a rendering problem: Which browser, which version? [Cannot reproduce so far](http://jsfiddle.net/CkyVh/)

Comment: better to add a [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: It's not CSS problem. It's a rendering problem, related to pixels on your monitor.

Comment: added html code, css and information about the browser being used ...

Answer (score 1):

the problem is, the two dotted border are conflicting, try to use a border : colapse

Comment: No, that can't be:
- 1. i am already using border collapse for the whole table
- 2. it should normally be an ----- row everywhere. Instead it is sometimes an ________ row. But this _____ row's position is changing as i zoom in / out!